# Limit of a power function with imaginary power

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, exponentiation

Is there is any precise notion of the limit

$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}x^\mu$

where $\mu$ is purely imaginary?

Comment: Of course this is to complete things, since the limit is $0$ if real part of $\mu$ is positive, and limit is complex infinity if real part of $\mu$ is negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x=e^{-n\pi}$ where $n$ is a (large) positive integer. Let $\mu=-i$.

Then $x^\mu=e^{in \pi}$.  By [Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula_in_complex_analysis), if $n$ is odd, then $e^{in \pi}= -1$, and if $n$ is even then $e^{in \pi}=1$.  As $n \to \infty$, $x \to 0^+$,  so the limit does not exist.

Other choices of positive $x$ arbitrarily near $0$ can give us any complex number on the unit circle.